# undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) for an array

Tags: ruby, file-io

I am trying to read a file which contains some numbers. And then i want to convert them into integer. When i'm trying like below, it is ok.

```
input = IO.readlines(filename)
size = input[0].split(/\s/).map(&:to_i)
```

But, when i'm trying like below, it gives me that error.

```
input = IO.readlines(filename)
lnth = input.length
i=0
while i<=lnth
  size = input[i].split(/\s/).map(&:to_i)
  i=i+1
end
```

> undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

How I solve the error now?

Comment: You end up with `i == input.length`, but `input[input.length]` does not exist (it is `nil`), hence the error. Try `while i < lnth`, although you can just do `input.each`.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers Perfect answer(very first also), why in comment ? post as an answer.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I guess you are right, I generally post comments to minor mistakes like index-out-of-bounds but I suppose I should just answer :) It just feels a bit silly to get reputation for changing `<=` to `<` and explaining it.

Comment: Then why are you thinking still ? Post, we will take care of it :-)

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers its developer sites, so it is worth to get some rep, while you are clearing other devs pains.. even if it is minimal one. Because sometimes these errors to fix take more time.. so you saved the time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously `while i<lnth` not `<=`:

```
while i<lnth
  size = input[i].split(/\s/).map(&:to_i)
  i=i+1
end
```

but preferably use:

```
size = line.split(/\s/).map(&:to_i)
```

Answer (score 2):

I wonder what this is supposed to do?

```
size = line.split(/\s/).map(&:to_i)
```

It will split a string like "321 123 432" and return an array like [321, 123, 432].
Also the variable `size` is initialized again on each round.

Ignoring that, here's a more Ruby-like version:

```
File.readlines(filename).each do |line|
  size = line.split(/\s/).map(&:to_i)
end
```

In Ruby you don't usually use anything like `for i in item_count ..` or `while i<item_count` since we have the Enumerators like .each.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I'm new in ruby. so it will help me a lot. I will follow your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to string before splitting, i.e `input[i].to_s.split(/\s/)`

may be `input[i]` is `nil`, so convert it to string

[ref](http://dev.mensfeld.pl/2013/01/ruby-on-rails-webrick-error-nomethoderror-undefined-method-split-for-nilnilclass/)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
def nil.split *args
  nil # splitting of nil, in any imaginable way, can only result again in nil
end
```